# Faceting by geolocation in Elasticsearch (clustering)

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, grouping, geocode

I have a project that enables users to search for POIs using Elasticsearch, and they can filter by a number of different attributes, including location. I'd like to add faceting to all of the filters, most of which are categorical variables for which faceting is perfect. However, I also want users to be able to facet by location/city/metro area. Each location is currently a lat/long pair.

From my research, it seems that the best approach is to use k-means clustering of the lat/long pairs to get the most common groupings of locations for faceting. Once I have those groupings, I would want to provide the most commonly recognizable name for the area (e.g., even if "Brooklyn" was the center of a cluster, I'd want to provide the name "New York City").

(a) Can geo-clustering (k-means, or any other way) be done in Elasticsearch to allow faceting by location? If so, how? If not, can this be done in Postgres instead?
(b) How can I make sure that I'm providing the most widely recognizable political name for any given region returned by the clustering?

Comment: Neither is good at clustering. k-means is also a rather poor choice. (how do you set k, and prevent it from cutting right through brooklyn?)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, obviously I am not an expert in this.  What method would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 1):

Given Lat/Long (or address) as input, you can use the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to retrieve (and index) specific hierarchically-scoped labels for:

- country
- administrative_area_level_1 (state:  in the US)
- administrative_area_level_2 (county: in the US)
- sublocality_level_1 (borough: in NYC)
- administrative_area_level_3 (city: in the US)
- locality (neighborhood: in the US)

If you're building out a Yelp or AirBnB-like search interface with a zoom-map component, you can choose which location facet to display based some diversity criteria:

---

e.g. request all 6 term facets, but only display the one with the appropriate selection diversity (say 2-10 terms) ... for example, if your zoom level (and bounding box) includes Brooklyn, Manhattan and Staten Island, then you'll see the following:

- country (United States) ... *ignore, too broad*
- administrative_area_level_1 (`New York`) ... *ignore, too broad*
- administrative_area_level_2 (`Kings County, New York County, Richmond County`) ... *ignore (just in the case of NYC where sublocality_level_1 is more commonly used)*
- sublocality_level_1: (`Brooklyn, Manhattan, Staten Island`) ... *appropriately specific, **show this!***
- administrative_area_level_3 (`New York City`) ... *ignore, too broad*
- locality (`<100s of neighborhoods>`)   ... *ignore, too narrow*